# How would this shell-sort algorithm be coded in recursive?

Tags: recursion, recursive-backtracking, shellsort

I understand that any iterative function can be written recursively, but I still don't quite understand how to write it as a recursive function.

This function receives an array (elements) and a int (number of elements), and sorts them from lower to higher, but I don't get how to make it recursive, any help would be appreciated!

```
void ShellSort(int *arr, int num){
    for (int i = num / 2; i > 0; i = i / 2)
    {
        for (int j = i; j < num; j++)
        {
            for(int k = j - i; k >= 0; k = k - i)
            {
                if (arr[k+i] >= arr[k])
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    arr[k]=arr[k] + arr[k+i];
                    arr[k+i]=arr[k] - arr[k+i];
                    arr[k]=arr[k] - arr[k+i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return ;
}
```

Comment: Recursion is where a method calls itself from within its definition..  Your method as you have pasted it does not call itself. Nowhere in the body of your method does it say again ShellSort()

Answer (score 0):

Here is the shell sort with recursion:

namespace Algorithm.ShellSort
{
internal class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
int[] ints = { 11, 2, 3, 1, 6, -1, 4, 2, -2 };

```
        int[] sorted = ShellSort(ints);

        foreach (int i in sorted)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static int[] ShellSort(int[] arr)
    {          
        int gap = 1;

        while (gap < arr.Length / 3)
            gap = 3 * gap + 1;

        while (gap >=1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                int left = i;
                int right = i + gap;

                Recursion(arr, left, right, gap);
            }

            gap /= 2;
        }

        return arr;
    }

    private static void Recursion(int[] arr, int left, int right, int gap)
    {
        if (left < 0)
            return;

        if (right >= arr.Length)
            return;

        if (arr[left] > arr[right])
        {
            Swap(arr, left, right);

            Recursion(arr, left - gap, right - gap, gap);
        }

        return;
    }

    private static void Swap(int[] arr, int i, int j)
    {
        if (i != j)
        {
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

}